# Can Apache deny access if REMOTE_USER doesn't match the subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, authorization

I'd like to deny access if the REMOTE_USER does not match SUBDOMAIN.example.com. The site is protected by `Require valid-user` (as usual). Currently anybody can access all areas so long as she's logged in.

The intended behavior is this:

- alice can access alice.example.com and nothing else
- bob can access bob.example.com and nothing else
- bonus points for granting all-access to admin

Sound too easy? **Here's the catch:** Subdomains/usernames are *dynamic*, so any hard-coded "alice" or "bob" strings do not count!

Is there any way I can do that with Apache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the apps I'm trying to authorize are all Rack apps, I've ended up implementing this as a Rack middleware, released as the [Portarius gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/portarius).